# Class of subsets which is not a $\sigma$-ring

Tags: measure-theory

I can't find a non-empty class that is closed under countable intersections and symmetric differences, but it's not a $\sigma$-ring. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite subsets of an infinite set.

Comment: A $\sigma$-ring has to be closed under a countable union. So if we take the union of countably finite subsets of an infinite set, why should said union not be contained in the infinite set?

Comment: The union of countably many distinct finite subsets is not a finite subset.

Comment: Yes, my mistake was I misread / misunderstood it as a union of **finitely** many countable subsets.